# Linear homogeneous equation $u_x + u_t + σ u = 0, u(x,0)=\sin x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Linear homogeneous equation $u_x + u_t + σ u = 0, u(x,0)=\sin x$

Use Lagrange characteristic method to solve the first order PDE:
$$\frac {dx}{1}=\frac {dt}{1}=-\frac {du}{σu}$$
First differential equation is easy to solve:
$ {dx}={dt}$ or $ t =  x +c_1,$ or $ \implies c_1=t-x.$ The second DE gives us: $\frac {dt}{1}=-\frac {du}{σu,}$ or $c_2=u e^{-σt}.$ Now the solution opf the PDE is
$$f(c_1)=c_2 \implies u=e^{σt} f(t-x)$$
I'm stuck on how to solve this linear homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 1):

Your correctly found the general solution :
$$u(x,t)=e^{\sigma t}f(t-x)$$
or equivalently
$$u(x,t)=e^{\sigma t}g(x-t)$$
$f(X)=g(-X)$ are undefined functions, to be determined according to a given condition.

Condition : $\quad u(x,0)=\sin(x)=e^{0}g(x-0)$

$$g(x)=\sin(x)$$
Now the function $g$ is determined.
We put it into the above general solution where the variable is $(x-t)$ . Thus $g(x-t)=\sin(x-t)$ . The solution is :
$$u(x,t)=e^{\sigma t}\sin(x-t)$$